# How to extract multiple line strings between two keywords using grepwin

Tags: grep

Hi I have a directory of files and each file has multiple languages text strings over multiple lines. Using grepwin I would like to extract all the English text strings and save into another text file. Typically in the each file the english text is inside a Switch/Case condition like this:

```
Default //English
    bitmap 8 20 "bmp5/warning.bmp"
    Ltext 5 1 11 "USB Device Overload"      
    LText 85 20 13 "USB"
    Ltext 50 33 13 "Device Overload!"
Break

Case _French
            bitmap 8 20 "bmp5/warning.bmp"
            LTEXT 5 1 11 "Surcharge clé USB!" 
            LTEXT 45 30 13 "Surcharge clé USB" 
Break
```

Since all the English text is always between 'Default' and 'Break' I want to use those two keywords as the delimeter. Finally all the text between the two keywords needs to be saved out to another text file.

Can anyone help at all.

Thanks guys

Comment: Not an answer, but the obvious (for me) tool for that would be gawk. Or some scripting language. Lua would be neat, because it's lightweight and easy to setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through grep.

```
$ grep -oPz '(?s)(?<=\n|^)Default\b[^\n]*\n\K.*?(?=\nBreak\b)' file
    bitmap 8 20 "bmp5/warning.bmp"
    Ltext 5 1 11 "USB Device Overload"      
    LText 85 20 13 "USB"
    Ltext 50 33 13 "Device Overload!"
```

To save the result to another file, you need to use output redirection operator.

```
grep -oPz '(?s)(?<=\n|^)Default\b[^\n]*\n\K.*?(?=\nBreak\b)' infile > outfile
```

From `man grep`

```
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj, I am using grepwin in Win8 (very new to this) and not at the command line so would that be a Regex search or just a text search?

Comment: it's a regex based text search :-)